# Problemas al iniciar Apache2 en ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

estoy teniendo problemas al iniciar apache, la verdad no se que pasa. Hace unos dias instale stacer y "apague" apache porque no lo usaba todo el tiempo, habia dos opciones, que no se ejecute y e otro era ponerlo como inactivo. Ya desintale ese programa pero intente ponerlo en activo de nuevo al apache antes de desintalarlo y no me dejo.

Hoy despues de intentar reiniciar el apache ejecute primero esto:

sudo systemctl status apache2

Ejecute luego:

sudo apachectl configtest

Adjunto captura de pantalla de la terminal. Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda.

[image: captura de pantalla de la terminal]

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx a SOes. Hazle caso a lo que ves y revisa los logs de apache. Lo mismo, te dice que el confioguration check falla; los archivos de configuración parecen tener errores.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, escribi esto:

tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

y me parecio:


tail: no se puede abrir '/var/log/apache2/error.log' para lectura: No existe el archivo o el directorio
tail: no queda ningún fichero

Comment: Hola, se pudo resolver con esto:
sudo apt-get purge apache2

Luego reinstale apache2 escribiendo:

sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: Súper! Ponlo como respuesta, abajo en el campo Tu Respuesta. Así otros sabrán qué hacer en el futuro. Incluso podrás aceptarla un rato después :)

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: tu pregunta tiene que ver con la configuracion de apache o el servidor y no es un problema de programacion ... tu post deberia estar en el sitio de https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

se pudo resolver con esto:

sudo apt-get purge apache2

Luego reinstale apache2 escribiendo:

sudo apt-get install apache2