# ¿Porqué el código php no se ejecuta y se muestra comentado en el codigo fuente del navegador?, el apache esta iniciado. Estoy en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php8

El problema es que en el navegador, google chrome o mozilla (probe en ambos), el archivo os.php, que está en la carpeta includes, no se ejecuta, este archivo lo llame desde index.php con una sentencia include de php: "`<?php include("includes/os.php");?>`".

Cuando escribo la ruta en el navegador: http://localhost/watch, solo me ejecuta el codigo html y css del index.php, pero el codigo php:"`<?php include("includes/os.php");?>`" no se ejecuta, y aparece comentado en el código fuente del navegador. El archivo os.php contiene codigo html. Informo también que tengo instalado PHP 8.0.12.

Recientemente tuve problemas con el apache, asi es que lo purge y reinstale: [Problemas al iniciar Apache2 en ubuntu 20.04](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/495879/257049)

Intente instalar un host virtual, pensando que solucionaria el problema que tenia con apache, aunque no se si tenia mucho que ver, lo lei en una publicación en otra parte.
¿Se podria solucionar desinstalando y reinstalando php?

Esto es parte del código de index.php:

```
<div class="exterior">
 <?php include("includes/os.php");?>
</div>
```

Captura de las carpetas del proyecto:

[image: Captura de las carpetas del proyecto]

Código php que aparece comentado en el codigo fuente del navegador:

[image: Código php aparece comentado en el navegador web]

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo php???

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo que nos muestras y en qué carpeta está?

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy casi seguro que tiene eso en un archivo `.html`  XD

Comment: ¿Si escribes en la consola `php -i` te muestra toda la información de PHP? Parece que tienes una instalación incorrecta o que las rutas de PHP están mal configuradas o algo así. Si tu archivo tiene la extensión `.php` y lo interpreta como texto entonces es que no te está reconociendo a PHP en ese entorno.

Comment: Mi archivo tiene la extension .php, es index.php. Cuando escribo php -i en la consola me aparece la información de php. Tengo instalado php 8.0.12.

Comment: Dinos si estás trabajando en un IDE o framework concreto y dinos también los pasos que realizas para intentar ejecurar tu archivo, todo apunta a una mala configuración o a que en el entorno en que estás trabajando no tienes indicada la ruta correcta de php.

Comment: dime algo tu URL en el navegador luce así: **http://localhost/tusitio/** o es diferente a esto; lo que tambien puede estar pasando es que estas abriendo el archivo php desde una ruta local en lugar de una URL interpretada por apache ...

Comment: Mi ruta es: localhost/watch, watch es la carpeta donde está mi proyecto. Me ejecuta el index.php, pero solo el código html y css del mismo (index.php). No estoy utilizando un IDE o framework; estoy utilizando visual studio code, y lo instalé desde ubuntu software.

Comment: Si reinstalaste Apache, yo ahora probaría a volver a instalar PHP8.

Comment: Si @Triby , instale php 8 desde la consola, mirando el tutorial que me pasaste llegue hasta la parte de "el servidor web Apache con PHP-FPM", la cual no instale por no necesitarla a mi juicio. Cuando escribo en consola: sudo vim /var/www/html/info.php, me aparece: sudo: vim: orden no encontrada. José Carlos PHP, según el tutorial que compartio Triby creo que ya reinstale php 8, lo tengo instalado, no estoy seguro si lo reinstalé.

Comment: @LuisCaleni, en Ubuntu el editor por defecto es nano, puedes remplazar el comando por `sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php` o usar cualquier editor de tu preferencia, siempre que puedas ejecutarlo como `root`. O, en todo caso, intenta instalar vim con `sudo apt install vim`

Comment: Perdona la pregunta, pero, ¿es seguro ejecutar una aplicación como root?, ¿podria solucionar mi problema?, de ser asi, ¿que aplicación seria o recomendarian?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @LuisCaleni, en este caso, se debe editar el archivo como `root` porque tiene permisos solo para el usuario bajo el que corre Apache, generalmente, `www-data` y no te va a permitir modificarlo con tu usuario. ¿Es seguro? Ya depende de lo que hagas.

Comment: Hola @Triby, ejecute como root: sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php, ya habia podido crear este archivo y guardarlo como info.php, pero al abrir el navegador me muestra directamente el codigo php como texto. como si hubiese puesto el codigo php entre etiquetas `<pre></pre>`. Tambien instale vim, pero no supe como usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de crear hosts virtuales, debes asegurarte de que todo funcione con las opciones por defecto. Lista de cosas a revisar:

1. Instalaste correctamente Apache y php8.0, junto con libapache2-mod-php8.0
2. Revisa la carpeta `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` (contiene todos los módulos que se han habilitado), ahí deberías tener dos archivos referentes a PHP:

   - php8.0.conf
   - php8.0.load
3. Si no aparecen, verifica que existen en la carpeta `/etc/apache2/mods-available` (contiene todos los módulos disponibles), si están, solo necesitas habilitar el módulo, entrando en la consola y tecleando los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

El primer comando es para habilitar el módulo y, el segundo, para reiniciar Apache.

Si no encuentras esos dos archivos, quiere decir que no instalaste el módulo y debes volver al paso 1. Por si no lo recuerdas, en la ventana de terminal ejecuta:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.0 libapache2-mod-php8.0
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

El primer comando es para actualizar la lista de repositorios, el segundo, para reinstalar PHP 8.0 y el módulo necesario para Apache, los otros dos ya sabes para qué son.

Revisa los mensajes de la consola, especialmente al instalar programas, es probable que alguno ya esté instalado en su versión más reciente o que algo falle y debas repetir el comando agregando al final de la línea `--fix-missing`; esto puede pasar por varias razones, como haber cambiado los repositorios para usar los más cercanos a tu ubicación.

Finalmente, si no consigues hacerlo funcionar, debes desinstalar y volver a intentarlo, pero primero asegúrate de tener tu sistema actualizado.

Comment: Encontre los dos archivos en la carpeta /etc/apache2/mods-available, pero al ejecutar el comando: sudo a2enmod php8.0, el mensaje de consola me muestra: "ERROR: El módulo mpm_event está habilitado; no puede continuar debido a conflictos. ¡Primero debe desactivarse!", "ERROR: No se pudo habilitar la dependencia mpm_prefork para php8.0". Estoy buscando como desactivar el módulo mpm_event, ¿esta bien?

Comment: Lo pude solucionar desintalando y reinstalando php como decias. El siguiente video de youtube me ayudo, es corto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHWBykJvj6s. Los comandos son 3 en total: `sudo apt-get purge 'php*'` ; `sudo apt-get update` y `sudo apt-get install php`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar desinstalando y reinstalando php como decian. El siguiente video de youtube me ayudó, es corto: youtube.com/watch?v=IHWBykJvj6s. Los comandos son 3 en total: `sudo apt-get purge 'php*'` ; `sudo apt-get update` y `sudo apt-get install php`. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Pero entonces instalaste PHP 7.3, que es la versión por defecto en Ubuntu 20.04LTS y en la pregunta especificaste la etiqueta `php8`. Al final, ¿la solución fue cambiar de versión?